# Proving that for any ordinal $\alpha$, ordinal exponentiation satisfies $\alpha \cdot \alpha^\omega =\alpha^\omega$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am having trouble verifying that $\alpha \cdot \alpha^\omega =\alpha^\omega$ for any ordinal $\alpha$.

The case is trivial for $\alpha = 0, 1$. So for $\alpha >1$ we get $\alpha^\omega = \bigcup_{n<\omega}\alpha^n$, which I beielve is a limit ordinal.

But I'm not sure how to figure out $\alpha \cdot \bigcup_{n<\omega}\alpha^n$.

Comment: The first two ones come from distributivity on the left which you should prove for all ordinals, and from the fact that $1+\omega = \omega$. The last one comes from the definition of ordinal exponentiation, and from the fact that for $n\geq 2$, the sequence $(n^m)_m$ is unbounded in $\omega$, and boundes by $\omega$ (by the way, $3)$ isn't true for $n=0,1$)

Comment: Intuitively, think of $A\omega$ as a string of $\omega$ copies of $A.$ Think of $A+B$ as $A$ followed (upward in the ordering) by a copy of $B.$ So $B= A\omega $ can be represented as $A_0,A_1,A_2,...$, where each $A_n$ is a copy of $A.$ If we precede this sequence with another copy $A_{-1}$ of $A,$ we get a representation of  $A+B=A+A\omega$ as $A_{-1},A_0,A_1,....$ But  each of these representations is a string of  $\mathbb N$ copies of A .

Comment: In ordinal arithmetic, $x(y+z)=(xy)+(xz).$  Think of $x(y+z)$ as a string of $(y+z)$  copies of $x$. But $y+z$ can be considered as  $y$ followed by a copy of $z$.  So $(y+z)$ copies of $x$ is "$y$ copies of $x$" followed by "$z$ copies of $x$", which is $(xy)+(xz).$....So, since $1+\omega =\omega,$ we have $A+(A\omega)=$ $(A\cdot 1)+(A\cdot \omega)=$ $A(1+\omega)=A(\omega)$..... Caution: In general, $(y+z)x$ is not equal to $(yx)+(yz).$

Comment: @Max How does the second one follow from distributivity?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 : I was saying "distributivity and $1+\omega =\omega$" for the two first ones, the second one is about $1+\omega =\omega$, not distributivity (sorry,that wasn't clear enough)

Comment: @Max I edited the question to highlight my difficulty. I still don't see how to figure out $\alpha \cdot \alpha^\omega$. I solved the other problems.

Comment: What's the definition of ordinal product ?

Comment: Yes exactly, and do you think that by any means, $\alpha^\omega$ could be a limit ordinal, such that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\delta<\alpha^\omega}\delta = \displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\alpha^n$ ?

Comment: @Max I don't understand. What does $\bigcup_{\delta < \alpha^\omega} \delta$ have to do with it?

Comment: @Max I know that $\alpha^\omega$ is a limit ordinal, but I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: a^w=a^(1+w)=a a^w .

Comment: If aaaaaaaaa... is well defined aaaaaaa... is a^w. This is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to what you said you only need help figuring out the last one.

The idea is to show that $\alpha\cdot \alpha^\omega = \alpha^{1+\omega}$ and from here, since $1+\omega =\omega $, you get what you want.

The important thing is that multiplication on the left is continuous by definition.

So $\alpha\cdot \alpha^\omega = \displaystyle\bigcup_{\delta< \alpha^\omega }\alpha\cdot \delta$, by definition. But for every $\delta <\alpha^\omega$, there exists $n\in \omega$ such that $\delta\leq \alpha^n$,and so (this you should prove) $\alpha\cdot \delta \leq \alpha\cdot \alpha^n$, and so

$\displaystyle\bigcup_{\delta< \alpha^\omega }\alpha\cdot \delta \leq \displaystyle\bigcup_{n<\omega }\alpha\cdot \alpha^n = \alpha^{1+\omega}$ by definition of $1+\omega$ and ordinal exponentiation (you should prove that $\alpha\cdot \alpha^n = \alpha^{1+n}$ for finite $n$). So $\alpha^{1+\omega}\geq \alpha\cdot\alpha^\omega$.

You can establish the reverse equality by noting that if $\alpha \geq 2$, then for every $n\in \omega$, $\alpha^n<\alpha^\omega$, and then do the same proof as I just did, but in the other direction.

Comment: How does continuity imply that for every $\delta < \alpha^\omega$, there is some $n\in \omega$ s.t. $\delta \leq \alpha^n$?

Comment: Well you know that for ordinals, union is the same thing as least upper bound, and since $\alpha^\omega =\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in \omega}\alpha^n$, then since $\delta<\alpha^\omega$, $\delta$ is strictly smaller than the l.u.b. of the $(\alpha^n)_n$, and so since the ordering of the ordinals is total, it has to be that some $\alpha^n\geq \delta$ (if you're not satisfied with this, try proving it by contradiction, remembering the connection "l.u.b./union")

Comment: I get it. Thank you so much for all the help.