# Ordinal Arithmetic: $\omega\cdot \omega^{\omega}=\omega^{\omega}$

Tags: ordinals

Someone please can help me out ? Please.
I am trying to use the definition of product ordinal and exponent ordinal.

Product ordinal:
$\beta \cdot \alpha=\sup \{\beta \cdot \delta: \delta<\alpha\}$

Exponent ordinal:
$\beta^\alpha=\sup \left\{\beta^\delta: \delta<\alpha\right\}$

can I define this one, in this way?

$\omega \cdot \omega^{\omega}=\sup\left\{\omega \cdot \omega^\alpha: \omega^\alpha<\omega^{\omega}\right\}.$

Is that possible?

Comment: No, you can't define it that way because you were given a different definition, but nobody is stopping you from *making a theorem* that proves the identity you want. Although personally I would advise against the specific instance.

Comment: Formatting note:  put $ before and after formulas to render

Comment: Try this argument with $\alpha=\omega$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2246812

Answer (score 1):

$\omega \cdot \omega^{\omega} = \omega^{1} \cdot \omega^{\omega} = \omega^{1+\omega} = \omega ^ {\omega}$

Note that for ordinals, $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, it is true that $\alpha^{\beta} \cdot \alpha^{\gamma} = \alpha^{\beta + \gamma}$.